How to Display News in a Timeline with Headline, Category, and Time?
I am working on a project where I need to display news articles in a timeline (Latest news). I want each news item to be structured as follows:
•   The title of the news article
•   Category (e.g., “Asia,” “Europe”) & Posting time
I only want to show the 5 latest news articles in the timeline.
Additionally, lower on the page, I want to display all the latest news of a given catergory (e.g. show all latest news for "Asia").
What would be the best way to achieve this layout? Are there any plugins or best practices for implementing a clean and efficient timeline with these elements?
Any tips would be be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

You can achieve this by creating Shortcodes for showing the the latest news and another to display all latest news of a given category.
Here is the shortcodes you can use:

[latest_news_timeline] => This is a shortcode to show the latest news.
[category_news] => This is a shortcode to display all latest news of a given category.

We need to add given code to functions.php file of the Theme.
<?php
/**
* This is to create shortcode to display the latest news.
*/
function show_latest_news_timeline() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post', // Here we can change post_type if you are using a custom post type.
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC'
    );

    $query  = new WP_Query($args);
    $output = '<div class="news-timeline">';

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $category      = get_the_category();
            $category_name = $category[0]->cat_name;
            $output       .= '<div class="news-item">';
            $output       .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            $output       .= '<span class="news-meta">' . $category_name . ' &middot; ' . get_the_date() . '</span>';
            $output       .= '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= 'No news found.';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'latest_news_timeline', 'show_latest_news_timeline' );

/**
* This is to create shortcode to display all latest news of a given category.
*/
function show_category_news_data( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'category' => ''
            ),
            $atts, 
            'category_news'
        );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post', // Here we can change post_type if you are using a custom post type.
        'category_name'  => $atts['category'],
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC'
    );

    $query  = new WP_Query($args);
    $output = '<div class="category-news">';

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $category      = get_the_category();
            $category_name = $category[0]->cat_name;
            $output       .= '<div class="news-item">';
            $output       .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            $output       .= '<span class="news-meta">' . $category_name . ' &middot; ' . get_the_date() . '</span>';
            $output       .= '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        $output .= 'No news found.';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'category_news', 'show_category_news_data' );

Also then you need to add given code to style.css file of your theme.
.category-news,.news-timeline{margin:20px 0}.news-item{margin-bottom:20px;padding:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}.news-item h2{margin:0 0 5px;font-size:20px}.news-meta{font-size:14px;color:#777}

Hope this should help you out.
